# React not rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm trying/playing around with React and have some issues that I cant seem to find on google and there's nothing in my console log? Can anybody tell me why this isn't working? React and ReactDOM libraries are included...

**HTML**

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

**JS**

```
class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
       <div>Hello</div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(App, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app')); For rendering App component has to rendered using jsx syntax, as <App />.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should render JSX element:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

You can't render a react component class, you need to render an element

Just so you understand why this is the case:

When you use JSX to create an element
your build process will transform it from

```
<App />
```

to

```
h("App", {}, null)
```

But If you just pass the class this conversion will not happen

Answer (score 0):

First You have to `import` the component:

```
import App from "./App";
```

Then render the component like `<App />`:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```